# json_decode returns NULL with validated json data, error: "Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded"

Tags: php, json

I'm using json data from https://apps.apple.com/se/app/mosaika/id515840296?dataOnly=true&isWebExpV2=true.

I've pasted this data into online validators and they all say json is valid.

However, in php (it's actually my own wordpress plugin), when decoding the data using json_decode I get NULL. And last json error message becomes "Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded"

I've tried removing control characters, but that didn't help. Not sure how to pinpoint the invalid characer(s), if any.

My server info: WordPress 5.2.3 with PHP 7.0.33-1~dotdeb+8.1. Upgrading PHP is not possible right now say admin.

```
<?php
$url = "https://apps.apple.com/se/app/mosaika/id515840296? 
dataOnly=true&isWebExpV2=true";
$response = wp_remote_get($url);
$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
$body = preg_replace('/[[:cntrl:]]/', '', $body);
$body = str_replace("\r\n", '\r\n', $body);
$body = str_replace("\n", '\n', $body);
$body = str_replace("\r", '\r', $body);

$json = json_decode($body, true);
if (is_array($json)) {
  // ...
} else {
  echo json_last_error_msg();
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you try without replacing the newline characters?

Comment: Yes, I added them when it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use plain `file_get_contents()` method from PHP to make GET request and it decoded successfully for me.

```
$url = "https://apps.apple.com/se/app/mosaika/id515840296?dataOnly=true&isWebExpV2=true";
$body = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($body, true);
```

Comment: @Niska I can confirm this works. Could it be your own plug-ins mess with the encoding?

Comment: You are correct. I was using another text filter that messed with the json text, although I'm not sure why. I removed it and it's now working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this by removing space after Query string `?` in url. It will work.

```
$url = "https://apps.apple.com/se/app/mosaika/id515840296?dataOnly=true&isWebExpV2=true";
    $response = wp_remote_get($url);
    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
    $body = preg_replace('/[[:cntrl:]]/', '', $body);
    $body = str_replace("\r\n", '\r\n', $body);
    $body = str_replace("\n", '\n', $body);
    $body = str_replace("\r", '\r', $body);

    $json = json_decode($body, true);

    if (!empty($json)) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($json);
    } else {
    echo json_last_error_msg();
    }
    die;
```